# Passing 900 parameters in SQL IN Clause multiple times and export to xlsx file using Java

Tags: java, oracle, apache-poi

I am passing different 900 Parameters in my SQL Query multiple times & want to write the all data in a single excel sheet in xlsx format

I have read all the 12000 data from an excel & stores into a Arraylist. Then I have divided that arraylist in chunks with data contained 900 & passing to query each time 900. Now, for the first time export 900 is sucessfull but when 2nd set of 900 parameters are pushed down it is giving me "Attempting to write a row[0] in the range [0,900] that is already written to disk."

```
package iCAPs;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook;

public class iCAPsRawData {
    public static final String SAMPLE_XLSX_FILE_PATH = "C:\\Users\\sm39766\\Desktop\\icaps\\A.xlsx";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

        Workbook writeWorkbook;

        ArrayList<String> GOCIds = new ArrayList<String>();

        List<String> sublist=new ArrayList<String>();

        Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(SAMPLE_XLSX_FILE_PATH));


        System.out.println("Workbook has " + workbook.getNumberOfSheets() + " Sheets : ");
        System.out.println("Retrieving Sheets using for-each loop");
        for (Sheet sheet : workbook) {
            System.out.println("=> " + sheet.getSheetName());
        }


        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        System.out.println("Before Starting Process Excel Content "+GOCIds.size());
        DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();
        System.out.println("\n\nIterating over Rows and Columns using for-each loop\n");
        for (Row row : sheet) {
            for (Cell cell : row) {
                String tempValue = "'"+dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell)+"'";
                System.out.println(tempValue);
                GOCIds.add(tempValue);
            }
        }
        Sheet desSheet = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        int columnsNumber = 0;
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = null;
        FileOutputStream fileOut = null;
        Connection cntn = null;
        writeWorkbook = new SXSSFWorkbook();
        desSheet = writeWorkbook.createSheet("GOC_");
        int size = 3;
        System.out.println("After Starting Process Excel Content "+GOCIds.size());
        for (int start = 0; start < GOCIds.size(); start += size) {
            int end = Math.min(start + size, GOCIds.size());
            sublist = GOCIds.subList(start, end);
            //System.out.println(sublist);
            String formattedString = sublist.toString()
                    .replace("[", "")
                    .replace("]", "")
                    .trim();
            //System.out.println(formattedString);

            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            cntn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@local:8888:OPDB", "tiger", "scoot");
            stmt = cntn.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select d.feed_id,\r\n" + 
                    "( Select path from COM_DATA.HIER_DOMAIN_DENORM where tree_id=1000 and node_id=d.ms_prnt_node_id) MS_Path,\r\n" + 
                    "( Select path from COM_DATA.HIER_DOMAIN_DENORM where tree_id=3000 and node_id=d.GEO_prnt_node_id) GEO_Path,\r\n" +
                    "( Select path from COM_DATA.HIER_DOMAIN_DENORM where tree_id=2000 and node_id=d.lv_prnt_node_id) LV_Path,\r\n" +  
                    "( Select path from COM_DATA.HIER_DOMAIN_DENORM where tree_id=4000 and node_id=d.func_prnt_node_id) FUNC_Path\r\n" + 
                    "from COM_DATA.HIER_GOC_DENORM d\r\n" + 
                    "where d.feed_id IN ("+formattedString+")");
            rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

            columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();

            /*ArrayList<String> feedID=new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<String> MS=new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<String> GEO=new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<String> LV=new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<String> FUNC=new ArrayList<String>();
            while (rs.next()){
            feedID.add(rs.getString(1));
            MS.add(rs.getString(2));
            GEO.add(rs.getString(3));
            LV.add(rs.getString(4));
            FUNC.add(rs.getString(5));
            }
            System.out.println("GOC_ID:"+feedID);
            System.out.println("MS:"+MS);
            System.out.println("GEO:"+GEO);
            System.out.println("LV:"+LV);
            System.out.println("FUNC:"+FUNC);*/


            Row desRow1 = desSheet.createRow(0);

            for (int col = 0; col < columnsNumber; col++) {
                Cell newpath = desRow1.createCell(col);
                newpath.setCellValue(rsmd.getColumnLabel(col + 1));
            }

            while (rs.next()) {
                Row desRow = desSheet.createRow(rs.getRow());
                for (int col = 0; col < columnsNumber; col++) {
                    Cell newpath = desRow.createCell(col);
                    newpath.setCellValue(rs.getString(col + 1));
                }
                System.out.println("Row Number -->" + rs.getRow());
            }
            fileOut = new FileOutputStream("GOCs.xlsx");
            writeWorkbook.write(fileOut);
        }
        workbook.close();
        writeWorkbook.close();

    }
}
```

Please let me know when I am passing more than 900 values in my query to fetch the data each time how can I store the values in one place & write it in a single excel file.

Comment: Do you want to have multiple sheets or all in 1 sheet? If its the latter, than you need to have a row counter and not use `desSheet.createRow(rs.getRow())` but rather `desSheet.createRow(rowNum);` and then increment the row every iteration. If you want multiple sheets, call `desSheet = writeWorkbook.createSheet("<custom name that changes>");` every iteration of your for loop. You get the error because you use `SXSSFWorkbook` which can only write each row once per sheet. As soon as the row is written, you have no longer access to it

Comment: One sheet... I want all the data exported to single sheet...also I am reading all data from a single sheet....can you please help to modify the code ? Appreciate your help on this

Comment: Hi Baumer, I have tried your suggestion but all things perfect but only column names are not coming in excel file

Answer (score 1):

```
int rowNum = 0;
for (int start = 0; start < GOCIds.size(); start += size) {
    ...
    Row desRow1 = desSheet.createRow(rowNum);
    rowNum++;
    while (rs.next()) {
        Row desRow = desSheet.createRow(rowNum);
        rowNum++;
    ...
    }
}
//after for loop
fileOut = new FileOutputStream("GOCs.xlsx");
writeWorkbook.write(fileOut);
workbook.close();
writeWorkbook.close();
```

As said in my comment:

- Create a row counter for all the data
- Use the row counter to create new rows
- Increment the row counter (never reset it)
- Write workbook to disk only after all data has been added